# Identify the first and last datapoint and assign to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Assumptions:

1. length of `y` is changeable, i.e: it will have additional value or less value
2. in any case, value of `x` is the multiplier of value in `y`, the multiplier may not be in the same for each set

Inputs:

```
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
x = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Objective: to identify the first and last data point in `x`, based on each set of value in `y`

Expected output:

```
[0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12]
```

My silly way of writing:

```
a = []

#first run
fst_index = x.index(y[0])
lst_index = len(x) - 1 - x[::-1].index(y[0])

a.append(fst_index)
a.append(lst_index)

#second run
fst_index = x.index(y[1])
lst_index = len(x) - 1 - x[::-1].index(y[1])

a.append(fst_index)
a.append(lst_index)

#third run
fst_index = x.index(y[2])
lst_index = len(x) - 1 - x[::-1].index(y[2])

a.append(fst_index)
a.append(lst_index)
```

How do I simplify the syntax with a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to create a dict from `x` to map each key to its starting and ending indices, and then iterate through `y` to output the respective indices:

```
from itertools import groupby

ranges = {k: (first, last) for k, ((first, _), *_, (last, _)) in groupby(enumerate(x), lambda t: t[1])}
print([i for k in y for i in ranges[k]])
```

This outputs:

```
[0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Manage to solve the above using a for loop as follows:

```
a = []

for i in range(len(y)):
    a.append(x.index(y[i]))
    a.append(len(x) - 1 - x[::-1].index(y[i]))
```

Comment: Why the `if i == 0:` condition when both blocks do the same thing?

Comment: you are right! i have edited accordingly~